# can Google Colab support a graphical interface like threejs or pythreejs?

Tags: google-colaboratory

This discussion explains the question better:
https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/pythreejs/issues/317#issuecomment-605389551

Colab pretty nicely supports the Trimesh graphics library, but apparently someone says it's not interactive in the sense of accepting python events or callbacks.  I wonder whether that functionality would be relatively easy to add?

This link shows what Colab can already do:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1n0UiVcmG1Ivajb2lBvXf5Uzh9nNtWU4g

If adding 2-way interactivity is difficult to do, then can the Trimesh widget state be modified in a python loop to just play a "video" (without necessarily taking python callbacks from the widget)?

Answer (score 0):

The discussion taking place here is answering this question:

https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/pythreejs/issues/317#issuecomment-605397472